# Drop list of fields from confluent <-> elastic connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

Using confluent cloud's elastic search connector to push data into elastic.
Is there a way to drop/pick only a list of fields ?

I read about transform option available in the connector, but couldnt find any to filter out or drop a list of fields from incoming event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ReplaceField](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/replacefield.html#replacefield) transform allows you to exclude/include particular fields.

If that's not available, the alternative is to use Kafka Streams/KsqlDB to create a new topic that the sink connector will read